# How to set ss and sp registers correctly in i386

Tags: assembly, operating-system, nasm, bootloader, i386

I am currently writing a bootloader and have begun to run out of space in my 512B, so I have begun writing more code outside the 512B and intend to use the bootloader to read it into memory. I have added to the end of my code:

```
stack_start:
    resb 4096
stack_end:
```

So that I can allocate space for the stack at the end of the operating system code. Currently in my bootloader, I allocate 4KiB for the stack after the bootloader using the following which I took from [here](http://mikeos.sourceforge.net/write-your-own-os.html):

```
mov ax, 07c0h           ; 4K stack space after the bootloader -- code is running at 0x07c0
add ax, 288             ; (4096 + 512)/16 bytes per paragraph (288 paragraphs)
mov ss, ax
mov sp, 4096            ; moves the stack pointer
```

However now I need a way to allocate the stack to be at the end of my OS code, which will be an unknown size.

I believe I understand how these need to be set up -- similar to using `es`, I am using `ss` for extending the addressing space, but I can't find anything that explains it well for my level of knowledge. I am also not sure how to set it correctly for putting my stack at the end. I have used:

```
mov ax, stack_start
mov ss, ax
mov sp, 4096
```

And have not encountered an error; however I would like to know if this is correct, or whether I've actually just allocated some space for the stack while filling memory with a higher address.

How does `ss` actually work? And how can I use it and `sp` to allocate memory for the stack at the end of my code?

This is in i386 using nasm.

EDIT: Some way to validate that the stack is in the right place would be really useful, too, if that is at all possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know this is scary for a beginner but there is no good or wrong way to setup the stack as long as it fulfils the requirements and it is bug-free.
Before you have a fully working memory manager, you (the human) have to be the memory manager.
You must be aware of how you use the memory.
The whole concept of "allocating memory" doesn't exist yet! You don't have a memory manager, you just have a bunch of RW RAM addresses.

### Document your assumptions

Start with requiring a minimum amount of memory that your bootloader can safely assume.
Since the Initial Program Loader (the bootloader) is at 0x7c00 it is reasonable to believe the system has 31,5KiB of memory. 
You can also assume that no memory is present and rely on the cache but that's and advanced topic.

Stating assumptions is vital when things go wrong.

### Mind the gaps

Then you must be aware of the reserved and used areas, this is achieved with a standard [memory map](http://wiki.osdev.org/Memory_Map_(x86)).

An excerpt:

```
00000 - 003ff   IVT
00400 - 004ff   BDA
00500 - 0052f   Dangerous Zone (The Petch Zone :) )
00530 - 07bff   Free
07c00 - 07dff   IPL
```

The "Petch Zone" [is an inside joke](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45283851/how-to-set-ss-and-sp-registers-correctly-in-i386/45285701?noredirect=1#comment77531969_45284108) and homage to [Michael Petch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3857942/michael-petch).

### Make a fully conscious decision

Build up your minimal environment by setting up a temporary stack.
In the fragment above the area `00530 - 07bff` is free you can use it as a ~29KiB stack.
Since the stack is full-descending you can put the stack pointer `ss:sp` at `07c00`.
`07c00` is a *physical address*, convert it to any suitable logical address (`0000:7c00`, `0001:7bf0`, `0002:7be0`, `0003:7bd0`, ..., `07c0:0000`, any will do pick up the one you like the most) and set `SS:SP` to it in any atomic way w.r.t. interrupts you know/like.

**EDIT** Using logical address with a small offset part leads to problems when the offset underflow wrapping from 0 to `fffe` as [Ped7g](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45283851/how-to-set-ss-and-sp-registers-correctly-in-i386/45285701?noredirect=1#comment77537397_45285701) correctly noted.
While the static behaviour checks (the starting address is the same) the dynamic behaviour fails, so it's better to use `0000:7c00` and surely not anything with segment above `0053`.

Any other area will do, setting the stack pointer to `a0000` (The end of the conventional memory) is another choice.
None is better, just be **aware** of where you put what.

**EDIT**: As [Michael Petch pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45283851/how-to-set-ss-and-sp-registers-correctly-in-i386/45285701?noredirect=1#comment77534008_45285701) in the comments, the address `a0000` is also dangerous.
A safer address would be `9c000`.

### Update the memory map

Update the memory map with the blocks that fit your needs.
Write down where your kernel starts and ends, where your dynamic data lies and so on.

For example

```
00000 - 003ff   IVT
00400 - 004ff   BDA
00500 - 0052f   Dangerous Zone (The Petch Zone :) )
00530 - 07bff   Stack
07c00 - 07dff   IPL
07e00 - 08fff   Kernel
09000 - 10000   Other kernel stuff
```

Until now you could have gone away with using static blocks in the memory map but if you want to use more than 1 MiB of memory you need to [query the BIOS](http://wiki.osdev.org/Detecting_Memory_(x86)) to get the memory map of available memory.
This is intrinsically dynamic as each system comes with a different amount of memory.

That map is nothing but a very minimal meta-data for a memory manager, so it is time to...

### Implement a simple memory manager

Within the basic environment you setup up to now, code a **simple** memory manager that book keeps blocks of memory.

*Pitfall*: A memory manager needs some "meta-memory" to hold its book of allocated memory, this call for an *assumption*.

Once you can allocate and free memory you can move the stack into a bigger area, load other data from disk or equivalent and so on.
The idea is that you can now manage memory dynamically like you do in C with `malloc` and `mfree` relieving you from the burden of mentally dealing with the memory map.

### More advanced memory manager

A more advanced memory manager is usually written in an high-level language where data manipulation is easier (especially when dealing with topics like Paging).

Comment: I'm the upvote. Might be worth noting that most BIOSes have their EBDA just below 0xA0000 as well. The size can usually be queried from the BDA (although in the real world some antiquated BIOS didn't report it correctly). I usually play it safe for a wide variety of hardware to top out somewhere around 0x9C000. If I know I'm on a 640k system I set SS:SP to something like 0x8c00:0x0000

Comment: Great answer, upvoted. You should just probably add a quick note about the "Petch zone", not having read the comment thread above it left me puzzled and I started looking for "Petch zone" on Google to no avail. 

Comment: Thank you for such an in-depth answer, Margaret, this is really helpful and clears up a lot of misconceptions I had.

Comment: About possible `ss:sp` settings... while `07c0:0000` is same physical address as `0000:7c00`, the `07c0:fffe` is not same as `0000:7bfe`! So actually `07c0:0000` will cause the problems, which lead the OP to this question, possibly overwriting the second stage code. The `ss:sp` pair must cover the lowest possible valid stack address, in this case probably `0053:0000` being minimum (I mean the lowest `ss`, which allows to use the full ~29kB block under first stage for stack).

Comment: Thank you @MichaelPetch, you always have invaluable information!

Comment: Ahah @Matteo, well... we should name it that way!  :)

Comment: Thank you @Ped7g! That was a silly mistake of mine! Great point! You are like a human debugger :)

Comment: *"You can also assume that no memory is present and rely on the cache but that's and advanced topic."*  Where can I read more about this "advanced topic"? Sounds interesting.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than putting your stack at the *end* of your code, put it at the beginning. This is actually pretty common practice for boot loaders.  In other words:

```
 cli
 mov ax,0x7c00
 mov sp, ax
 xor ax, ax
 mov ss, ax
 sti
```

You are now growing down from where your boatloader code loads. This also makes things easier since one of the very next things you are going to do is to load a second stage. This allows you to easily create the second stage in the same assembly file, load it in and jump to it, without having to worry about the stack overwriting code.

Comment: So in this instance, do I essentially just allow the stack to start overwriting my code and immediately load in a second stage to after the stack finishes, and jump to it?

Comment: That's dangerous code, you should load `sp` immediately after `ss` to avoid interrupt trouble (if you don't have them disabled).

Comment: This doesn't actually put the stack at the beginning of the code either. Because you set _SP_ to 0 stack will wrap to the top of the 0x7c0 segment on the first push.

Comment: Oops!  Thanks.  Wrote that too quickly.

Comment: Take note that I've edited this to reverse the SP and SS registers.

Comment: Reversing doesn't help fix the issue identified by Jester. what happens if an interrupt occurs between updating _SP_ and _SS_? Interrupts will be turned off for the next instruction after updating the _SS_ register. Doing something like `xor ax, ax`  `mov ss, ax` `mov sp, 0x7c00` would work. After _SS_ is updated interrupts will be off through to the end of the next instruction (which is the update of SP in my example). The other way is to ensure interrupts are off until SS:SP is updated (issue _CLI_ before SS;SP update and turn them on some time later)

Comment: How much space does this allocate for the stack?

Comment: @WORD_559 You don't really allocate space using SS:SP it just sets where the stack pointer is. But if you place it below 0x7c00 as in this example you have a stack that can grow downward towards about 0x500 (0x530 with ancient IBM PCs) before overwriting the BIOS Data Area and the interrupt vector table. That gives you about 30k of stack before pushing any more may alter the behavior of the system.

Comment: Jeez... I'm not trying to write the boot loader! I'm just giving an example of putting the stack below the code. I added cli and sit to satisfy the nits.

Comment: @MichaelPetch If you load `ss`, interrupts are disabled for the next instruction so you can load `sp` immediately afterwards and be fine. (cf. the [documentation](https://c9x.me/x86/html/file_module_x86_id_176.html)) If this is too uncomfortable, either use `lss` to load both or disable interrupts.

Comment: @fuz : I already said that and provided an example in my comment that does just that. I said: _Interrupts will be turned off for the next instruction after updating the SS register. Doing something like `xor ax, ax` `mov ss, ax` `mov sp, 0x7c00` would work_

Comment: @MichaelPetch That makes sense. I presume doing it this way also leaves me with about 30KiB for the OS code too? (0x7c00 - 0x07c0) And I could increase this amount (at the cost of stack space) by increasing the initial value of `sp`? (for example to 0x8000 for an extra KiB?)

Comment: @WORD_559 No, David's example sets the stack using a different segment (he uses 0x0000). The stack will grow down beneath 0x0000:0x7c00. 0x0000:0x7c00 in real mode segmentation is actually the same physical address 0x7c0;0x0000 points at. Your code would have the full 64kb available to it running from 0x7c0:0x0000 to 0x7c0:0xffff (inclusive)
 which is physical addresses 0x07c00 to 0x17bff (inclusive)

Comment: @MichaelPetch Right, okay. So if I wanted to "reserve" 4k for my stack, would I then load my second stage into 0x0000:0x1000 and jump to there, allowing the bootloader to be overwritten? Sorry, I'm new to OS development so all of this is a bit confusing still.

Comment: @WORD_559 : That is an entirely different question and makes me wonder if you posted an XY problem. No where in your question did you say anything about loading a second stage and where it would be. Setting SS:SP doesn't allocate space. It sets the stack pointer. It is up to you to make sure it is placed in such a way that it won't interfere with your code or memory regions taken by hardware etc.

Comment: @Jester `cli` disabled interrupts, so it's totally safe

Comment: @VladislavToncharov code was edited after my comment. Also I said "if you don't have them disabled", so.

Answer (score 1):

One of the things I do in my startup code is to put the stack as high in conventional memory as possible.

> ```
>    SYS_MEM    equ 12H
>    StkSize    equ 44  ; # of 1024 byte blocks to reserve for stack
> ```

```
     int    SYS_MEM     ; 1K blocks to EBDA
     sub    ax, StkSize ; 1K blocks for stack
     shl    ax, 6       ; * 64 = Base segment of stack

; Align stack on 4k boundary for PLM4 mapping.

     xor    al, al
     mov    es, ax
     xor    cx, cx      ; Guarantees MSB of CX will be NULL
     mov    di, cx      ; ES:DI = Destination
     mov    ch, StkSize*2   ; Block size * 512 = 16 bit words
     or     ax, -1      ; Fill pattern FFFF
     rep    stosw

; DI points to TOS, bump it back for a 96 byte scratch area and 14
; values that were preserved in prolog.

     sub    di, 124 
     mov    si, sp
     mov    cl, 14      ; Registers saved in prolog
    push    di
     rep    ss movsw    ; Copy to new stack frame
     mov    bp, di      ; BP = Base of 96 byte scratch buffer.

; This may look a little odd, but retrieving the value that was saved
; three instructions ago, does work.

     cli
     pop    sp
    push    es
     pop    ss      ; SS:SP = TOS
     sti
```

There are a few things here that are peculiar to my requirements, but essentially I grab 44k at the top of memory and that is where the stack lives until I drop into 64 bit.

Then the code that reads the kernel is moved to 540H and kernel (*1181 sectors*) is read in from 1000H to 94600H in my case. I've found this to be very practical while in real and protected modes.